# jQuery draggable: Stop dragging when mouse out of parent

Tags: jquery, draggable, mouseout

Please check out this [jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2h2w/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="button_area"></div>
        <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="button_area"></div>
        <div class="icon"></div>    
    </div>
</div>​
```

This is the html code, and I am dragging the .button_area:

```
$('.button_area').draggable({});
```

It is working as it is suppused to except for one thing. When I click on the red area (in the second yellow square) and start dragging toward left (first yellow square) I want it to stop the drag process when the mouse gets over second yellow square (parent).... not the draggable object (helper)... THE MOUSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with sokie's and Lunik's help, I did it: [jsFIDDLE SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2h2w/7/)

Thanks guys.

```
$( ".button_area" ).draggable({});

$(".item").mouseout(function() {
    $( '.button_area' ).draggable( 'option',  'revert', true ).trigger( 'mouseup' );
});
```

Comment: You should take a look at the containment property of dragable aswell,it does everything for you,without the need to do custom code to limit,as i showed you here http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: :S have you even checked the example I provided in jsfiddle? I don't want the draggable to be contained since it has to go into negative border!!! I want to stop dragging when MOUSE pointer is out of the container... I explicitly emphasized that!

Comment: i was only giving out a link for further documentation,i wasn't imposing anything to you

Answer (score 3):

You must only modify your jquery this way

```
$( ".button_area" ).draggable({
drag: function(event, ui) { 
  if(my_condition) 
      return false; }
  });​
```

Tip!

one example would be something along this:

```
$( ".button_area" ).draggable({
drag: function(event, ui) { 
  if($('.button_area').offset().left > 50) 
  { 
     $( '.button_area' ).draggable( 'option',  'revert', true ).trigger( 'mouseup' );
  } 
 }
 });​
```

Comment: heh, I know that... now tell me what "my_condition" is ;)

Comment: Better use 
$(".item")​.mouseout(function() {
/* Stop code here*/
    });​

Comment: SO shouldn't be a code writing site,we can point you in the right direction,not write code for you,jquery documentation even gives you a dragable demo and tut about constrains http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: Yeah. We can see in docs, a "containment" property of draggable. Useful for this question.

Comment: @sokie: you were giving me the obvious, what I already knew. I was asking for a specific thing. how to stop dragging when the mouse is out of the draggable parent..obviously I was doing some testing and digging before posting it here. anyway, thanks for you time.. will check it out

Comment: see,a little research was all that was needed.

Comment: I did all the reserach, without the help provided here I wouldn't have made so quickly, thanks

Comment: this is a very straight forward answer. I keep a data-locked attribute that i can control then check for it on dragand either return or not.